# Show direction in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, show, direction

I want to show the direction of the specified source and destinatinos (by passing the lat-long) of both the points in the Google Map.

I have searched a lot but there is so much of confusion in several answers I got.

Is there anyway simple way out to show the Map direction from one specified Lat-Long point to the another specified Lat-Long Point.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate for showing root on google map it is.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Here saddr means source address latitude and longitude
and  daddr means destination address latitude and longitude.
I hope its helpful to you..